# Inline Edit is not working on admin grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, inline-editor

I need some **columns** of my **grid** to be **clickable** and **editable**, I'm doing what magento tutorials say but its not working.

I've tried almost everything, and rows are not clickable and the editor does not appear. I think that the inlineEdit isnt even activated on my magento or something like that since i have tried all.

Thanks for the help.

Here is my code for columns part in `listing.xml`

```
 <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="sellermania/market/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.spinner_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>

</listing>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but shouldn't your file be named 
sellermania_market_listing.xml same as your data namespace?

Comment: yes, its his name, the grid works properly, the problem is when i try to do some columns editable, its like i did nothing, nothing changes ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know what was exactly the solution but now it works:

```
<columns name="spinner_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="sellermania/market/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.spinner_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.spinner_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="enabled">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Enabled</label>
            </settings>
        </column>


    </columns>

</listing>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes in this line:

```
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing_columns_editor</item>
```

change it to:

```
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sellermania_market_listing.sellermania_market_listing.spinner_columns_editor</item>
```

and of course don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: Done, and still nothing.

Comment: Did you clear cache? Your xml structure seems to be ok. There's all just the same in my listing.xml and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes,I cleared cache like 1000 times and compile code and nothing